# Unable to type INR sign in 18.10

Tags: keyboard, unicode, 18.10

I am not able to type symbol for Indian rupees using my 18.10. I have set Regional format as English ( India ) and in other areas where I can find English ( India ). But when I type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, I get 4 on gedit. Any fix available for this? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: When you ctrl+shift+u to enter utf8 number codes you can release the keys, you should have an underlined u symbol on screen. This is kinda a bypass, there should probably be a altrgr/compose-key method too.

Comment: I tried based on another answer which is removed now. I just need a fix for the INR icon. Is there one available ? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it ₹

First, you need to take " Language and Region " under " Input Sources " choose " English ( India with Rupees ) " and bring it to the top as seen in the image below.

[image]

Now you will hope that when you type <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> ₹ sign will appear. No, you will have to choose it from the top bar as well as seen below

[image]